# python subprocess awk with -F option and using variable for input file

Tags: python, awk, subprocess

I have a text file that has data delimited with '|'

E.g.

123 | 456 | 789

I want to print the second column only.
I can use awk in the shell like this: awk -F'|' '{print $2}' file.txt

However, I want to use python subprocess to do this. And also the input file must be a variable.

Right now, this is what I have.

```
import subprocess

file = "file-03-10-2016.txt"

with open('another_file.txt', 'wb') as output:
var = subprocess.check_call(['awk', '{print $2}', file])
print var
```

This prints the second column but it uses space as a delimiter. I want to change the delimiter to '|' using the -F option for awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var = subprocess.check_call(['awk', '-F|', '{print $2}', file])
```

However, I feel like I should point out that this task is very easy to do in pure python:

```
def awk_split(file_name, column, fs=None):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file_stream:
        for line in file_stream:
            yield line.split(fs)[column]

for val in awk_split(file, 1, fs='|'):
    # do something...
```

Comment: Thanks! This one worked for me. Also, thank you for sharing the pure python way. I'm familiar with bash and just recently learning python so this helps me understand it more.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.check_call` takes a list of strings that are joined with space characters and passed to the shell.  So you can just add the `-F'|'` argument as an item in the list.  The only catch, is that the list is using single quotes.  If you want to be consistent, you need to escape the single quotes in your argument:

```
var = subprocess.check_call(['awk', '-F\'|\'', '{print $2}', file])
```

Alternatively, python also accepts doublequotes as string delimiters:

```
var = subprocess.check_call(['awk', "-F'|'", '{print $2}', file])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You shouldn't be quoting the pipe in your awk call.  Normally people put the quotes there for the _shell_ (since `|` has special meaning to a shell), but there isn't a shell here to interpret the `|` so it can be passed directly.